# Average Function (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, average

Im just starting out and im trying to run some basic SQL functions. I want to do the average function which (by every site I've looked it up on) should just go like this:

```
SELECT AVG(column_name) FROM table_name
```

But that isn't working for me. It always says AVG is an invalid column name.

Also bonus question, in the basic SELECT column_Name from table_name format, I always have to go forward and type out the table name first and then go back and write the column name, or else SQL doesn't recognize the column.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying `SELECT AVG(column_name) FROM table_name` this query on numeric column then it should work.

For the second question, without typing table name, how can SQL recognize column names? You can install Redgate SQL Toolbelt which will be helpful for IntelliSense in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Microsoft SQL Server then you should be able to copy the following code and run it.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (
  SomeDate date,
  SomeValue float
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (SomeDate, SomeValue)
  VALUES ('20150801', 15.0),
  ('20150802', 11.0),
  ('20150803', 9.0),
  ('20150804', 10.5),
  ('20150805', 17.4),
  ('20150806', 21.6),
  ('20150807', 12.3),
  ('20150808', 15.9),
  ('20150809', 18.7),
  ('20150810', 7.6);

SELECT
  AVG(tt.SomeValue)
FROM @TestTable AS tt;
```

Maybe you can update your tags and let us know which `SQL` you are running. If the `average` funtion does not work for you then maybe you haven't setup the `table` corretly, maybe there is not data in it, maybe you have, ...
A great place to get started and learn more about `SQL` and all it's mysteries might be **http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp**. At the end of each newly learned lesson is the button "**Try it yourself**" to just do that. Another great place might be **http://sqlfiddle.com/** where you can fiddle around with some code and learn something new.